# Animating SVG with CSS ideas?

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm working on some animation where I first create the svg files in Illustrator then i'm trying to animate them with css or some library ( anime.js) .

I run in to a problem where I don't know how to hide the code and make it visible only in the screen.

```css
@keyframes scrolling {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translateY(-400px);
 }
}

.code {
 animation: scrolling 5s linear infinite;
}

/*  colors */
body{
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #111116;
}
.st0 {
  opacity: 0.17;
} 
.st1 {
 fill: #56aeec;
}
.st2 {
 fill: #2c65cc;
}
.st3 {
 fill: #2984d6;
}
.st4 {
 fill: #ccccff;
}
.st5 {
 fill: #8dfcff;
}
.st6 {
 fill: #38e0eb;
}
.st7 {
 fill: #e0fa09;
}
.st8 {
 fill: #ff49a5;
}
.st9 {
 fill: #ff3333;
}
.st10 {
 fill: #00ff66;
}
.st11 {
 fill: #ff6666;
}
.st12 {
 fill: #ff66cc;
}
```

```html
<svg width="180" height="375" viewBox="0 0 180 375">
  <g class="code">
    <path class="st4" d="M107.7,313.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C108.8,313.1,108.3,313.6,107.7,313.6z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M161,319.6h-94c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h94c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C162.1,319.1,161.6,319.6,161,319.6z"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M51.7,319.6H36.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h14.8c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C52.8,319.1,52.3,319.6,51.7,319.6z"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M134.7,313.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C135.8,313.1,135.3,313.6,134.7,313.6z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M120.7,313.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C121.8,313.1,121.3,313.6,120.7,313.6z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M147.7,313.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C148.8,313.1,148.3,313.6,147.7,313.6z"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M160.7,313.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C161.8,313.1,161.3,313.6,160.7,313.6z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M51.7,313.6H16.7c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h34.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C52.8,313.1,52.3,313.6,51.7,313.6z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M95.6,313.6H60.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h34.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C96.7,313.1,96.2,313.6,95.6,313.6z"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M28.6,319.6H16.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h11.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C29.7,319.1,29.2,319.6,28.6,319.6z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M25.2,330.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C26.7,329.8,26,330.5,25.2,330.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M25.2,337.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C26.7,336.8,26,337.5,25.2,337.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M25.2,344.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C26.7,343.8,26,344.5,25.2,344.5z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M35.2,351.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C36.7,350.8,36,351.5,35.2,351.5z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M35.2,358.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C36.7,357.8,36,358.5,35.2,358.5z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M35.2,365.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C36.7,364.8,36,365.5,35.2,365.5z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M60.2,330.5H42c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,329.8,61,330.5,60.2,330.5z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M60.2,337.5H42c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,336.8,61,337.5,60.2,337.5z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M60.2,344.5H42c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,343.8,61,344.5,60.2,344.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M60.2,351.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,350.8,61,351.5,60.2,351.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M60.2,358.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,357.8,61,358.5,60.2,358.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M60.2,365.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,364.8,61,365.5,60.2,365.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M92.2,330.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C93.7,329.8,93,330.5,92.2,330.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M92.2,337.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C93.7,336.8,93,337.5,92.2,337.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M92.2,344.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C93.7,343.8,93,344.5,92.2,344.5z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M82.2,351.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C83.7,350.8,83,351.5,82.2,351.5z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M82.2,358.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C83.7,357.8,83,358.5,82.2,358.5z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M82.2,365.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C83.7,364.8,83,365.5,82.2,365.5z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M117.2,330.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,329.8,118,330.5,117.2,330.5z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M117.2,337.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,336.8,118,337.5,117.2,337.5z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M117.2,344.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,343.8,118,344.5,117.2,344.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M117.2,351.5h-18c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,350.8,118,351.5,117.2,351.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M117.2,358.5h-18c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,357.8,118,358.5,117.2,358.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M117.2,365.5h-18c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,364.8,118,365.5,117.2,365.5z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M156,329h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,328.7,156.4,329,156,329z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M156,334.9h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,334.6,156.4,334.9,156,334.9z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M156,340.9h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,340.6,156.4,340.9,156,340.9z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M156,346.8h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,346.5,156.4,346.8,156,346.8z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M156,352.8h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,352.5,156.4,352.8,156,352.8z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M156,358.7h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,358.4,156.4,358.7,156,358.7z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M156,364.7h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,364.4,156.4,364.7,156,364.7z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M35.2,371.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C36.7,370.8,36,371.5,35.2,371.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M60.2,371.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,370.8,61,371.5,60.2,371.5z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M82.2,371.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C83.7,370.8,83,371.5,82.2,371.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M117.2,371.5h-18c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,370.8,118,371.5,117.2,371.5z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M156,370.7h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,370.4,156.4,370.7,156,370.7z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M126,224.6h-94c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h94c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C127.1,224.1,126.6,224.6,126,224.6z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M75.8,217.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h59.9c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C77.3,216.8,76.7,217.5,75.8,217.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M21.7,224.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C22.8,224.1,22.3,224.6,21.7,224.6z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M64.6,231H16.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h48.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C65.3,230.7,65,231,64.6,231z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M64.6,236.9H16.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h48.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C65.3,236.6,65,236.9,64.6,236.9z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M64.6,242.8H16.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7v0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h48.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7v0C65.3,242.4,65,242.8,64.6,242.8z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M64.6,248.6H16.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h48.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C65.3,248.3,65,248.6,64.6,248.6z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M23.6,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h7.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C24.3,254.2,23.9,254.5,23.6,254.5z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M36.4,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h7.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C37.2,254.2,36.8,254.5,36.4,254.5z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M49.3,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h7.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C50.1,254.2,49.7,254.5,49.3,254.5z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M62.2,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h7.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C62.9,254.2,62.6,254.5,62.2,254.5z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M75.1,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h7.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C75.8,254.2,75.5,254.5,75.1,254.5z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M88,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H88c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C88.7,254.2,88.4,254.5,88,254.5z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M64.6,260.4H16.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h48.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C65.3,260.1,65,260.4,64.6,260.4z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M164.1,235.8h-59.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h59.4c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C165.1,235.4,164.7,235.8,164.1,235.8z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M130.7,242.7h-26c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1v0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h26c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1v0C131.7,242.2,131.3,242.7,130.7,242.7z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M164.1,242.7h-27.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h27.4c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C165.1,242.2,164.7,242.7,164.1,242.7z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M164.1,260.9h-59.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h59.4c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C165.1,260.5,164.7,260.9,164.1,260.9z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M164.1,266.2h-59.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h59.4c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C165.1,265.7,164.7,266.2,164.1,266.2z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M30.9,289.1H16.7c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h14.2c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C31.9,288.6,31.4,289.1,30.9,289.1z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M30.9,285H16.7c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h14.2c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C31.9,284.5,31.4,285,30.9,285z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M30.9,280.8H16.7c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h14.2c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C31.9,280.4,31.4,280.8,30.9,280.8z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M30.9,276.7H16.7c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h14.2c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C31.9,276.3,31.4,276.7,30.9,276.7z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M53.3,276.7H49c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C54.3,276.3,53.9,276.7,53.3,276.7z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M43.3,285H39c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C44.3,284.5,43.9,285,43.3,285z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M53.3,280.8H49c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C54.3,280.4,53.9,280.8,53.3,280.8z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M43.3,289.1H39c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C44.3,288.6,43.9,289.1,43.3,289.1z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M62.3,285H58c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C63.3,284.5,62.9,285,62.3,285z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M62.3,289.1H58c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C63.3,288.6,62.9,289.1,62.3,289.1z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M71.3,276.7H67c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C72.3,276.3,71.9,276.7,71.3,276.7z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M71.3,280.8H67c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C72.3,280.4,71.9,280.8,71.3,280.8z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M130.7,247.7h-26c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1v0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h26c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1v0C131.7,247.2,131.3,247.7,130.7,247.7z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M164.1,247.7h-27.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h27.4c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C165.1,247.2,164.7,247.7,164.1,247.7z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M134,276h-30c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h30c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C134.7,275.7,134.4,276,134,276z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M163.6,280.9h-43.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h43.2c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C164.3,280.6,164,280.9,163.6,280.9z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M143.2,284.8h-39c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h39c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C143.9,284.4,143.6,284.8,143.2,284.8z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M162.7,288.6h-35.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h35.2c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C163.4,288.3,163.1,288.6,162.7,288.6z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M164,271.4h-59.8c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H164c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C164.7,271.1,164.4,271.4,164,271.4z"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M21.7,137.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C22.8,137.1,22.3,137.6,21.7,137.6z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M160,144.6h-94c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h94c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C161.1,144.1,160.6,144.6,160,144.6z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M75.8,151.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h59.9c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C77.3,150.8,76.7,151.5,75.8,151.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M48.7,144.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C49.8,144.1,49.3,144.6,48.7,144.6z"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M48.7,137.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C49.8,137.1,49.3,137.6,48.7,137.6z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M34.7,137.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C35.8,137.1,35.3,137.6,34.7,137.6z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M61.7,137.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C62.8,137.1,62.3,137.6,61.7,137.6z"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M74.7,137.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C75.8,137.1,75.3,137.6,74.7,137.6z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M111.6,137.6H80.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h30.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C112.7,137.1,112.2,137.6,111.6,137.6z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M159.6,137.6h-34.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h34.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.7,137.1,160.2,137.6,159.6,137.6z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M34.7,144.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C35.8,144.1,35.3,144.6,34.7,144.6z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M75.8,157.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h59.9c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C77.3,156.8,76.7,157.5,75.8,157.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M34.2,164.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,163.8,35,164.5,34.2,164.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M34.2,171.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,170.8,35,171.5,34.2,171.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M34.2,178.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,177.8,35,178.5,34.2,178.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M34.2,185.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,184.8,35,185.5,34.2,185.5z"/>
    <path class="st6" d="M34.2,192.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,191.8,35,192.5,34.2,192.5z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M159.6,163.9H50.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h108.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.7,163.3,160.2,163.9,159.6,163.9z"/>
    <path class="st12" d="M59.6,170.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C60.7,170.3,60.2,170.9,59.6,170.9z"/>
    <path class="st12" d="M73.6,170.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C74.7,170.3,74.2,170.9,73.6,170.9z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M159.6,177.9H50.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h108.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.7,177.3,160.2,177.9,159.6,177.9z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M59.6,184.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C60.7,184.3,60.2,184.9,59.6,184.9z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M73.6,184.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C74.7,184.3,74.2,184.9,73.6,184.9z"/>
    <path class="st5" d="M159.6,191.9H50.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h108.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.7,191.3,160.2,191.9,159.6,191.9z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M59.6,198.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C60.7,198.3,60.2,198.9,59.6,198.9z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M73.6,198.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C74.7,198.3,74.2,198.9,73.6,198.9z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M34.2,199.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,198.8,35,199.5,34.2,199.5z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M110.6,184.9H79.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h30.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C111.7,184.3,111.2,184.9,110.6,184.9z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M87.6,198.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C88.7,198.3,88.2,198.9,87.6,198.9z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M101.6,198.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C102.7,198.3,102.2,198.9,101.6,198.9z"/>
    <path class="st12" d="M117.6,170.9H79.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h37.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C118.7,170.3,118.2,170.9,117.6,170.9z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M159.1,170.9h-4.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h4.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.2,170.3,159.7,170.9,159.1,170.9z"/>
    <circle class="st9" cx="17.6" cy="128.7" r="1.9"/>
    <circle class="st7" cx="25.2" cy="128.7" r="1.9"/>
    <circle class="st10" cx="32.8" cy="128.7" r="1.9"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M159.1,184.9h-4.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h4.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.2,184.3,159.7,184.9,159.1,184.9z"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M159.1,198.9h-4.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h4.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.2,198.3,159.7,198.9,159.1,198.9z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M75,130H43.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H75c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C75.7,129.7,75.4,130,75,130z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M112,130H80.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H112c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C112.7,129.7,112.4,130,112,130z"/>
  </g>   
  <g class="screen">
    <g class="st0">
      <polygon class="st1" points="172.2,71.1 172.2,53.5 118.6,107.1 136.2,107.1"/>
      <polygon class="st1" points="79.9,107.1 172.2,14.8 172.2,8.7 131.2,8.7 32.8,107.1"/>
      <polygon class="st1" points="6,51.5 6,91.3 88.6,8.7 48.8,8.7"/>
    </g>
    <path class="st2" d="M175.2,123.9H5c-2.8,0-5-2.3-5-5v-6.2c0-2.8,2.3-5,5-5h170.1c2.8,0,5,2.3,5,5v6.2C180.2,121.6,178,123.9,175.2,123.9z"/>
    <path class="st3" d="M175.2,0H5C2.3,0,0,2.3,0,5v105.2h180.2V5C180.2,2.3,178,0,175.2,0z M172.2,107.1H6V8.7h166.2V107.1z"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

I'm able to modify the SVG and I'm open for any ideas.

Link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whzn5myc/5/?fbclid=IwAR3O8JtVQq2F-RLnfRQAxRieob5NNnYcr6MIAJaO5K9n_g60ez7lsROJtiY)

Comment: You can also take a look at masks to achieve this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add svg into a div and set the `height` and `overflow:hidden`.

```css
@keyframes scrolling {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translateY(-400px);
 }
}

.code {
 animation: scrolling 5s linear infinite;
}

.svg-container {
  height:124px;
  width:180px;
  overflow:hidden;
}






/*  colors */
body{
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #111116;
}
.st0 {
  opacity: 0.17;
} 
.st1 {
 fill: #56aeec;
}
.st2 {
 fill: #2c65cc;
}
.st3 {
 fill: #2984d6;
}
.st4 {
 fill: #ccccff;
}
.st5 {
 fill: #8dfcff;
}
.st6 {
 fill: #38e0eb;
}
.st7 {
 fill: #e0fa09;
}
.st8 {
 fill: #ff49a5;
}
.st9 {
 fill: #ff3333;
}
.st10 {
 fill: #00ff66;
}
.st11 {
 fill: #ff6666;
}
.st12 {
 fill: #ff66cc;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
<svg width="180" height="375" viewBox="0 0 180 375">
    <g class="code">
     <path class="st4" d="M107.7,313.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C108.8,313.1,108.3,313.6,107.7,313.6z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M161,319.6h-94c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h94c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C162.1,319.1,161.6,319.6,161,319.6z"/>
     <path class="st4" d="M51.7,319.6H36.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h14.8c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C52.8,319.1,52.3,319.6,51.7,319.6z"/>
     <path class="st4" d="M134.7,313.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C135.8,313.1,135.3,313.6,134.7,313.6z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M120.7,313.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C121.8,313.1,121.3,313.6,120.7,313.6z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M147.7,313.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C148.8,313.1,148.3,313.6,147.7,313.6z"/>
     <path class="st4" d="M160.7,313.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C161.8,313.1,161.3,313.6,160.7,313.6z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M51.7,313.6H16.7c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h34.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C52.8,313.1,52.3,313.6,51.7,313.6z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M95.6,313.6H60.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h34.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C96.7,313.1,96.2,313.6,95.6,313.6z"/>
     <path class="st4" d="M28.6,319.6H16.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h11.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C29.7,319.1,29.2,319.6,28.6,319.6z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M25.2,330.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C26.7,329.8,26,330.5,25.2,330.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M25.2,337.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C26.7,336.8,26,337.5,25.2,337.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M25.2,344.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C26.7,343.8,26,344.5,25.2,344.5z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M35.2,351.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C36.7,350.8,36,351.5,35.2,351.5z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M35.2,358.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C36.7,357.8,36,358.5,35.2,358.5z"/>
     <path class="st9" d="M35.2,365.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C36.7,364.8,36,365.5,35.2,365.5z"/>
     <path class="st9" d="M60.2,330.5H42c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,329.8,61,330.5,60.2,330.5z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M60.2,337.5H42c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,336.8,61,337.5,60.2,337.5z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M60.2,344.5H42c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,343.8,61,344.5,60.2,344.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M60.2,351.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,350.8,61,351.5,60.2,351.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M60.2,358.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,357.8,61,358.5,60.2,358.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M60.2,365.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,364.8,61,365.5,60.2,365.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M92.2,330.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C93.7,329.8,93,330.5,92.2,330.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M92.2,337.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C93.7,336.8,93,337.5,92.2,337.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M92.2,344.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C93.7,343.8,93,344.5,92.2,344.5z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M82.2,351.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C83.7,350.8,83,351.5,82.2,351.5z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M82.2,358.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C83.7,357.8,83,358.5,82.2,358.5z"/>
     <path class="st9" d="M82.2,365.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C83.7,364.8,83,365.5,82.2,365.5z"/>
     <path class="st9" d="M117.2,330.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,329.8,118,330.5,117.2,330.5z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M117.2,337.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,336.8,118,337.5,117.2,337.5z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M117.2,344.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,343.8,118,344.5,117.2,344.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M117.2,351.5h-18c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,350.8,118,351.5,117.2,351.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M117.2,358.5h-18c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,357.8,118,358.5,117.2,358.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M117.2,365.5h-18c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,364.8,118,365.5,117.2,365.5z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M156,329h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,328.7,156.4,329,156,329z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M156,334.9h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,334.6,156.4,334.9,156,334.9z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M156,340.9h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,340.6,156.4,340.9,156,340.9z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M156,346.8h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,346.5,156.4,346.8,156,346.8z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M156,352.8h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,352.5,156.4,352.8,156,352.8z"/>
     <path class="st9" d="M156,358.7h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,358.4,156.4,358.7,156,358.7z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M156,364.7h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,364.4,156.4,364.7,156,364.7z"/>
     <path class="st9" d="M35.2,371.5H17c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C36.7,370.8,36,371.5,35.2,371.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M60.2,371.5h-8c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C61.7,370.8,61,371.5,60.2,371.5z"/>
     <path class="st9" d="M82.2,371.5H74c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h8.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C83.7,370.8,83,371.5,82.2,371.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M117.2,371.5h-18c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C118.7,370.8,118,371.5,117.2,371.5z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M156,370.7h-23.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H156c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C156.7,370.4,156.4,370.7,156,370.7z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M126,224.6h-94c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h94c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C127.1,224.1,126.6,224.6,126,224.6z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M75.8,217.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h59.9c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C77.3,216.8,76.7,217.5,75.8,217.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M21.7,224.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C22.8,224.1,22.3,224.6,21.7,224.6z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M64.6,231H16.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h48.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C65.3,230.7,65,231,64.6,231z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M64.6,236.9H16.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h48.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C65.3,236.6,65,236.9,64.6,236.9z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M64.6,242.8H16.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7v0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h48.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7v0C65.3,242.4,65,242.8,64.6,242.8z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M64.6,248.6H16.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h48.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C65.3,248.3,65,248.6,64.6,248.6z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M23.6,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h7.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C24.3,254.2,23.9,254.5,23.6,254.5z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M36.4,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h7.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C37.2,254.2,36.8,254.5,36.4,254.5z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M49.3,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h7.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C50.1,254.2,49.7,254.5,49.3,254.5z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M62.2,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h7.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C62.9,254.2,62.6,254.5,62.2,254.5z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M75.1,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h7.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C75.8,254.2,75.5,254.5,75.1,254.5z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M88,254.5h-7.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H88c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C88.7,254.2,88.4,254.5,88,254.5z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M64.6,260.4H16.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h48.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C65.3,260.1,65,260.4,64.6,260.4z"/>
     <path class="st11" d="M164.1,235.8h-59.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h59.4c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C165.1,235.4,164.7,235.8,164.1,235.8z"/>
     <path class="st11" d="M130.7,242.7h-26c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1v0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h26c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1v0C131.7,242.2,131.3,242.7,130.7,242.7z"/>
     <path class="st11" d="M164.1,242.7h-27.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h27.4c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C165.1,242.2,164.7,242.7,164.1,242.7z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M164.1,260.9h-59.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h59.4c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C165.1,260.5,164.7,260.9,164.1,260.9z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M164.1,266.2h-59.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h59.4c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C165.1,265.7,164.7,266.2,164.1,266.2z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M30.9,289.1H16.7c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h14.2c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C31.9,288.6,31.4,289.1,30.9,289.1z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M30.9,285H16.7c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h14.2c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C31.9,284.5,31.4,285,30.9,285z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M30.9,280.8H16.7c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h14.2c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C31.9,280.4,31.4,280.8,30.9,280.8z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M30.9,276.7H16.7c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h14.2c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C31.9,276.3,31.4,276.7,30.9,276.7z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M53.3,276.7H49c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C54.3,276.3,53.9,276.7,53.3,276.7z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M43.3,285H39c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C44.3,284.5,43.9,285,43.3,285z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M53.3,280.8H49c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C54.3,280.4,53.9,280.8,53.3,280.8z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M43.3,289.1H39c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C44.3,288.6,43.9,289.1,43.3,289.1z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M62.3,285H58c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C63.3,284.5,62.9,285,62.3,285z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M62.3,289.1H58c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C63.3,288.6,62.9,289.1,62.3,289.1z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M71.3,276.7H67c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C72.3,276.3,71.9,276.7,71.3,276.7z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M71.3,280.8H67c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h4.3c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C72.3,280.4,71.9,280.8,71.3,280.8z"/>
     <path class="st11" d="M130.7,247.7h-26c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1v0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h26c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1v0C131.7,247.2,131.3,247.7,130.7,247.7z"/>
     <path class="st11" d="M164.1,247.7h-27.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1,1-1h27.4c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1l0,0C165.1,247.2,164.7,247.7,164.1,247.7z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M134,276h-30c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h30c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C134.7,275.7,134.4,276,134,276z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M163.6,280.9h-43.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h43.2c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C164.3,280.6,164,280.9,163.6,280.9z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M143.2,284.8h-39c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h39c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C143.9,284.4,143.6,284.8,143.2,284.8z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M162.7,288.6h-35.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h35.2c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C163.4,288.3,163.1,288.6,162.7,288.6z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M164,271.4h-59.8c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H164c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C164.7,271.1,164.4,271.4,164,271.4z"/>
     <path class="st4" d="M21.7,137.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C22.8,137.1,22.3,137.6,21.7,137.6z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M160,144.6h-94c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h94c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C161.1,144.1,160.6,144.6,160,144.6z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M75.8,151.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h59.9c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C77.3,150.8,76.7,151.5,75.8,151.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M48.7,144.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C49.8,144.1,49.3,144.6,48.7,144.6z"/>
     <path class="st4" d="M48.7,137.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C49.8,137.1,49.3,137.6,48.7,137.6z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M34.7,137.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C35.8,137.1,35.3,137.6,34.7,137.6z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M61.7,137.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C62.8,137.1,62.3,137.6,61.7,137.6z"/>
     <path class="st4" d="M74.7,137.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C75.8,137.1,75.3,137.6,74.7,137.6z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M111.6,137.6H80.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h30.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C112.7,137.1,112.2,137.6,111.6,137.6z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M159.6,137.6h-34.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h34.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.7,137.1,160.2,137.6,159.6,137.6z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M34.7,144.6h-6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C35.8,144.1,35.3,144.6,34.7,144.6z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M75.8,157.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5l0,0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h59.9c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5l0,0C77.3,156.8,76.7,157.5,75.8,157.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M34.2,164.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,163.8,35,164.5,34.2,164.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M34.2,171.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,170.8,35,171.5,34.2,171.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M34.2,178.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,177.8,35,178.5,34.2,178.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M34.2,185.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,184.8,35,185.5,34.2,185.5z"/>
     <path class="st6" d="M34.2,192.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,191.8,35,192.5,34.2,192.5z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M159.6,163.9H50.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h108.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.7,163.3,160.2,163.9,159.6,163.9z"/>
     <path class="st12" d="M59.6,170.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C60.7,170.3,60.2,170.9,59.6,170.9z"/>
     <path class="st12" d="M73.6,170.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C74.7,170.3,74.2,170.9,73.6,170.9z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M159.6,177.9H50.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h108.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.7,177.3,160.2,177.9,159.6,177.9z"/>
     <path class="st11" d="M59.6,184.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C60.7,184.3,60.2,184.9,59.6,184.9z"/>
     <path class="st11" d="M73.6,184.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C74.7,184.3,74.2,184.9,73.6,184.9z"/>
     <path class="st5" d="M159.6,191.9H50.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h108.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.7,191.3,160.2,191.9,159.6,191.9z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M59.6,198.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C60.7,198.3,60.2,198.9,59.6,198.9z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M73.6,198.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C74.7,198.3,74.2,198.9,73.6,198.9z"/>
     <path class="st9" d="M34.2,199.5H16c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5v0c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5h18.3c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v0C35.7,198.8,35,199.5,34.2,199.5z"/>
     <path class="st11" d="M110.6,184.9H79.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h30.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C111.7,184.3,111.2,184.9,110.6,184.9z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M87.6,198.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C88.7,198.3,88.2,198.9,87.6,198.9z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M101.6,198.9h-8.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h8.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C102.7,198.3,102.2,198.9,101.6,198.9z"/>
     <path class="st12" d="M117.6,170.9H79.9c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h37.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C118.7,170.3,118.2,170.9,117.6,170.9z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M159.1,170.9h-4.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h4.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.2,170.3,159.7,170.9,159.1,170.9z"/>
     <circle class="st9" cx="17.6" cy="128.7" r="1.9"/>
     <circle class="st7" cx="25.2" cy="128.7" r="1.9"/>
     <circle class="st10" cx="32.8" cy="128.7" r="1.9"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M159.1,184.9h-4.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h4.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.2,184.3,159.7,184.9,159.1,184.9z"/>
     <path class="st10" d="M159.1,198.9h-4.6c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2l0,0c0-0.6,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2h4.6c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2l0,0C160.2,198.3,159.7,198.9,159.1,198.9z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M75,130H43.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H75c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C75.7,129.7,75.4,130,75,130z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M112,130H80.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7l0,0c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7H112c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C112.7,129.7,112.4,130,112,130z"/>
    </g>   
    <g class="screen">
     <g class="st0">
      <polygon class="st1" points="172.2,71.1 172.2,53.5 118.6,107.1 136.2,107.1"/>
      <polygon class="st1" points="79.9,107.1 172.2,14.8 172.2,8.7 131.2,8.7 32.8,107.1"/>
      <polygon class="st1" points="6,51.5 6,91.3 88.6,8.7 48.8,8.7"/>
     </g>
     <path class="st2" d="M175.2,123.9H5c-2.8,0-5-2.3-5-5v-6.2c0-2.8,2.3-5,5-5h170.1c2.8,0,5,2.3,5,5v6.2C180.2,121.6,178,123.9,175.2,123.9z"/>
     <path class="st3" d="M175.2,0H5C2.3,0,0,2.3,0,5v105.2h180.2V5C180.2,2.3,178,0,175.2,0z M172.2,107.1H6V8.7h166.2V107.1z"/>
    </g>
    
   </svg>
      </div>
```